# How can I load form post data into a model while updating a record in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to update a record with the post data from a form. Every time I'm manually assigning the values from the form to the model and saving the record.

```
$model = CondoFacilities::find($id);

$model->facility_title = Input::get('facility_title');
$model->facility_description = Input::get('facility_description');
$model->facility_image = $imageName;

$status = $model->save();
```

Is there any way to assign the form data to the model and save/update the record in Laravel ? Similar to the one in YII2:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $model->save();
}
```

I'm new to Laravel hope this awesome feature is available in Laravel as well.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to create a model and store it in the database, you can use `create` method directly on the model like so:

```
YourModel::create($request->all());
```

where `$request->all()` is the post request of the form with the values that you wish to create and save it in the database.

Similarly, for updating the model, you need to first find the model:

```
$model = YourModel::find($id);
```

where `$id` is the unsigned integer of the model that you wish to update.

```
$model->update($request->all());
```

Of course you can also inline the update method like so:

```
YourModel::find($id)->update($request->all());
```

Read more about [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) and [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What should I do if I want to assign single column manually and save along with rest of the form values as:

    $model->facility_image = $imageName;
    $model->update($request->all());

Comment: You can use `$request['yourColumnName'] = YourValue;` where `yourColumnName` exists in the `$fillable` array of the model and also in the database table.

Comment: I have used `$request['condo_facility_image'] = $imageName;` where `condo_facility_image` was an file id in the form and was trying to updated `$model->update($request->all());` after update the values is not `$imageName` but from the form file.

So I have renamed the form id to `condo_facility_image_temp` and after update the value is `$imageName`. Is this procedure ok ?

Comment: I don't know what is there in your form. So I am least possible help to you in this unless you update your question to show the form code as well..

Comment: I guess the procedure I followed is correct and I'm getting the expected output. Your answer helped me :) Thank you once again.

Comment: Okay.. I am glad to help you out. Cheers. :)